# Skip rows while reading multiple excel worksheets in R

Tags: r

I am using **readxl** library to read many excel worksheets in the same excel workbook (called **data.xlsx**) with the following format:

Data starts in row 3.

```
  row1
  row2
 companyName   1980    1981    1982 ... 2016
 company1       5       6       7        8
 company2       10      20      30       40
 company3       20      40      60       80
 ....
```

The data range is different in length by each row and column. However, they have the **companyName** as common key. The **year** range varies from starting from 1980 or 1990 until 2016. The **worksheet name** is the **data name**.

I want to create a single excel where all data are extracted from all worksheets.

```
 companyName   Year   dataname     values
 company1      1980   sheetname1     5
 company1      1981   sheetname1     6
 company1      1982   sheetname1     7
 company1      ...    sheetname1     ...
 company1      2016   sheetname1     8
 company2      1980   sheetname1     10
 company2      1981   sheetname1     20
 company2      1982   sheetname1     30
 company2      ...    sheetname1     ...
 company2      2016   sheetname1     40
 ....          ....     ...           ...
 company1      2000    sheetname2     xxx
 company1      2001    sheetname2     yyy
  etc
  etc
  etc
```

This is how far I managed to get too:

```
  library(tidyverse)
  library(readxl)
  library(data.table)

   #read excel file (from [here][1])
   file.list<-"data.xlsx"

     **#read all sheets (and **skip** first two rows)**

   df.list <- lapply(file.list,function(x) {
     sheets <- excel_sheets(x)
     dfs <- lapply(sheets, function(y) {
       read_excel(x, sheet = y,skip=2)
       })
     names(dfs) <- sheets
     dfs
   })
```

I have following issues:

- the first two rows are not been skipped
- how I create one dataframe with only select sheets only (ie. sheet 5, sheet 10 and sheet 15).

Thank you for your help.

Source:
[R: reading multiple excel files, extract first sheet names, and create new column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42115412/r-reading-multiple-excel-files-extract-first-sheet-names-and-create-new-colum)

Comment: What version is your `readxl` package? I have no issues with skipping rows. Unless not all sheets in your file start with the same number of rows before the headers.

Comment: Hello - using package 1.0.0 of readxl. Yes some sheets need to be excluded, how do I do that please?

Comment: Do you mean the `skip`s vary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just removed one level of nesting from `df.list`.

```
df.list <- lapply(file.list,function(x) {
    sheets <- excel_sheets(x)
    dfs <- lapply(sheets, function(y) {
    read_excel(x, sheet = y,skip=2)
  })
  names(dfs) <- sheets
  dfs 
})[[1]]
```

This works for me. I can't replicate your problem with skips. Also, if the rows are just blank rows, `read_excel()` should skip them by default using `trim_ws = TRUE`.

I used the following list just to demonstrate what to do after the import.

```
df.list <- structure(list(sheetname1 = structure(list(companyName = c("company1", 
"company2", "company3"), `1980` = c(5, 10, 40), `1981` = c(6, 
20, 50), `1982` = c(7, 30, 60)), .Names = c("companyName", "1980", 
"1981", "1982"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), sheetname2 = structure(list(companyName = c("company1", 
"company2", "company3"), `1980` = c(6, 11, 42), `1981` = c(7, 
21, 52), `1982` = c(8, 31, 62)), .Names = c("companyName", "1980", 
"1981", "1982"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), sheetname3 = structure(list(companyName = c("company1", 
"company2", "company3"), `1990` = c(8, 12, 43), `1991` = c(9, 
22, 53), `1992` = c(10, 32, 63)), .Names = c("companyName", "1990", 
"1991", "1992"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))), .Names = c("sheetname1", "sheetname2", 
"sheetname3"))
```

The following works even if the years start at 1980 or 1990.

```
dat <- lapply(df.list, function(x){
  nrows = nrow(x)
  years = names(x[,2:nrows])
  x %>% gather(year, values, -companyName)
}) %>% enframe() %>% unnest()

dat

# # A tibble: 27 x 4
#    name       companyName year  values
#    <chr>      <chr>       <chr>  <dbl>
#  1 sheetname1 company1    1980      5.
#  2 sheetname1 company2    1980     10.
#  3 sheetname1 company3    1980     40.
#  4 sheetname1 company1    1981      6.
#  5 sheetname1 company2    1981     20.
#  6 sheetname1 company3    1981     50.
#  7 sheetname1 company1    1982      7.
#  8 sheetname1 company2    1982     30.
#  9 sheetname1 company3    1982     60.
# 10 sheetname2 company1    1980      6.
# # ... with 17 more rows
```

You can now use the specific `sheetname` by using `dplyr::filter()`.

For example:

```
dat %>% filter(name == "sheetname1")

#   name       companyName year  values
#   <chr>      <chr>       <chr>  <dbl>
# 1 sheetname1 company1    1980      5.
# 2 sheetname1 company2    1980     10.
# 3 sheetname1 company3    1980     40.
# 4 sheetname1 company1    1981      6.
# 5 sheetname1 company2    1981     20.
# 6 sheetname1 company3    1981     50.
# 7 sheetname1 company1    1982      7.
# 8 sheetname1 company2    1982     30.
# 9 sheetname1 company3    1982     60.
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend the package `openxlsx` which allows you to specify `startRow`, and `melt` from the package `reshape2` which enables to change a data frame to a long format in an easy manner.

```
library(openxlsx)
library(reshape2)

first.Row <- 6 # supposing the data starts at row 6
sheets.2.read <- loadWorkbook(file.list)$sheet_names # retrieving the sheet names
df <- data.frame()
for(tmp.sheet in sheets.2.read){
  tmp.dat <- read.xlsx(file.list, sheet = tmp.sheet, startRow = first.Row, colNames = TRUE)
  tmp.dat <- cbind(melt(tmp.dat, id.vars = "companyName"), tmp.sheet)
  df <- rbind(df, tmp.dat)
}
```

Here is my output with some dummy data (printing only 10 rows):

```
> df[c(1:3, 50:53, 300:302),]
    company.name variable     value tmp.sheet
1          comp7     1968 0.3359298    Sheet1
2          comp8     1968 0.3359298    Sheet1
3          comp9     1968 0.3359298    Sheet1
50        comp16     1966 0.3359298    Sheet2
51        comp17     1966 0.3359298    Sheet2
52        comp18     1966 0.3359298    Sheet2
53        comp19     1966 0.3359298    Sheet2
300       comp16     2000 0.3359298    Sheet3
301       comp17     2000 0.3359298    Sheet3
302       comp18     2000 0.3359298    Sheet3
```

Comment: thank you. If I only want sheets 5, 10 and 15, how can do I update the code?

Comment: @hpesoj626  - thank you. The skips do not vary. But unsure how to only select sheets 5, 10 and 15 from excel workbook to read.

Comment: you could either add the line `sheets.2.read <- sheets.2.read[c(5,10,15)]` right after `sheets.2.read <- loadWorkbook(...)` or you can just right away define `sheets.2.read <- c("sheet5", "sheet10", "sheet15")`