# Issue Merging all sheets from multiple Excel Workbooks

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, import-from-excel

I'm currently trying to merge multiple workbooks from excel with hundreds of sheets in each.  Some of the sheets have different columns and there are columns with different lengths within some workbooks as well.  I tried to accomplish this utilizing the method laid out in this thread [R: reading multiple excel files, extract first sheet names, and create new column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42115412/r-reading-multiple-excel-files-extract-first-sheet-names-and-create-new-colum) .

Utilizing that code I received the following error:

Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
Item 2 has 128 columns, inconsistent with item 1 which has 7 columns. To fill missing columns use fill=TRUE.

I changed the last line of code from the other thread to the following:

```
rbindlist(lapply(df.list, rbindlist, id = "id"), fill=TRUE, use.names=TRUE)
```

But the error did not change.  Any help in solving this problem would be incredible

Comment: I think you need the `fill = TRUE` inside as well i.e. `rbindlist(lapply(df.list, rbindlist, fill = TRUE, idcol = "id"), fill=TRUE, use.names=TRUE)` or use `bind_rows` which does automaticlaly, `map_dfr(df.list, bind_rows, .id = 'id')`

Comment: Hey Connor, Can you create a dummy example? It sounds like you have two tables (at least) that have different column headers. From my perspective, without more info, it would seem to make sense to keep the tables separate. Or to add in some intermediate steps to process the tables so `rbind` will work smoothly.

Comment: Hi Nick, there are quite a few things going on with the data including different column headers, it's a messy dataset.  Each workbook has a summary sheet that is in a vastly different format to the rest of the sheets.  Each sheet is a dated report pulled from salesforce, with "copywright" information in the 4 cells of the first column after the table.  Every few months the order of the columns or number of columns changes.  I will need to do time series analysis, and the best way I know how is combining this into one datasheet, and filtering out the sheet name "summary" and copywright data.

Comment: @akrun I ran your suggested edit and ran into another error: Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : Class attribute on column 50 of item 3 does not match with column 61 of item 2.

Comment: It is because of type mismatch.  May be change all the columns types to a single one before binding